# How to fix this error I get while attempting to execute a Lua file via C++?

Tags: c++, lua

I'm trying to execute a Lua file using C++.

I'm running Mac OS X and Lua 5.3 is located in /usr/local/include

When I try to execute the Lua file, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "lua_settop(lua_State*, int)", referenced from:
      _main in lual-8d0dcd.o
  "luaopen_base(lua_State*)", referenced from:
      main::lualibs in lual-8d0dcd.o
  "luaL_newstate()", referenced from:
      _main in lual-8d0dcd.o
  "lua_close(lua_State*)", referenced from:
      _main in lual-8d0dcd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is the C++ file:

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    lua_State *lua_state;
    lua_state = luaL_newstate();

    static const luaL_Reg lualibs[] = {
        { "base", luaopen_base },
        { NULL, NULL}
    };

    const luaL_Reg *lib = lualibs;
    for(; lib->func != NULL; lib++) {
        lib->func(lua_state);
        lua_settop(lua_state, 0);
    }

    luaL_dofile(lua_state, "helloworld.lua");

    lua_close(lua_state);

    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an `extern "C"` block around your includes:

```c
extern "C" {
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>
}
```

The reason for this is that Lua is written in C, and therefore exports functions the "C way" by simply using the function name as symbol name. Your C++ program expects the symbols to be named the "C++ way" which includes encoded type information. The `extern "C"` block forces C-style symbol naming.

As @ChrisBeck suggests, you can just add Lua sources into your project, and compile them as if they were C++. Then the functions would be exported with C++-style names.

Comment: Might want to mention alternative, that they can import the lua sources into their project and compile it as C++, then they don't need the `extern "C"` block. there are good reasons that a lot of projects do that

Comment: I implemented what you said by including "lua.hpp" (it's contents are `extern "C" { ... }`.  I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @David: Either you should compile lua separately as C, and then use `extern "C"` wherever you include it, OR compile it as C++ and then DO NOT use `extern "C"`. If you do both you will get the same error as doing neither. Basically the issue is that C++ does something called name-mangling to make its functions look like C functions, and whenever you call something it will look for the mangled version of that name. Extern "C" more or less disables the mangling when looking up symbols.